# tensorflow import error can somebody help me

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
import keras
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, Input, Activation
from keras import optimizers
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(4)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(4)
from util import csv_to_dataset, history_points
```

Using TensorFlow 2.0 as backend and got following errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sander/PycharmProjects/autotrader/basic_model.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorflow import set_random_seed
ImportError: cannot import name 'set_random_seed' from 'tensorflow' (C:\Users\sander\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py)
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: How are you importing TensorFlow?

Answer (score 2):

set_random_seed is a function not a module, have you tried following steps?

In tf 1.x, do it as this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(4)
```

In tf 2.0, do this as this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(4)
```

Comment: i get this C:\Users\sander\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/sander/PycharmProjects/autotrader/tech_ind_model.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sander/PycharmProjects/autotrader/tech_ind_model.py", line 9, in <module>
    tf.set_random_seed(4)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'set_random_seed'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @sandertuin, what is your tf version?

Comment: tensorflow 2.0.0

Comment: @sandertuin, in tf2, you should do it like this "tf.compat.v1.random.set_random_seed(4)"

Comment: Or use `tf.random.set_seed`.